# d3 liquidfilledguage does not work with d3 version 4

Tags: d3.js

specifically, it fails on this code:

```
waveGroup.attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+waveRiseScale(0)+')')
            .transition()
            .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
            .attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+waveRiseScale(fillPercent)+')')
            .each("start", function(){wave.attr('transform','translate(1,0)'); });
```

Where waveGroup results from a call to d3.select and is a d3 object.

the fail occurs on the call to ".each" which has apparently changed in d3 version 4. It nolonger accepts a string as the first parameter.
The error is "callback.call is not a function"
Simply removing the first parameter causes errors elsewhere.

Is their a version of liquidfilledguages what works with d3 version 4?

Comment: I assume it will be more successful for you to file this as an issue against https://github.com/jonbgallant/PowerBI-visuals-liquidFillGauge/issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6)

Use [this](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) change log to migrate from v3 to v4.

change `.each("start", ... )` to `.on("start",....)`

Along with that you need to do all the migration changes.